# What species of esrog do people use?

Tags: minhag, sukkot, agriculture, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

I know Lubavitchers are makpid to use only Esrogim from Genoa (if not grown there, at least that species).

What do other communities use?

Does anyone still use Korfu?

Comment: Are Geonan _esrogim_ a separate species? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Citron_varieties) implies otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps _varietal_? or _cultivar_? I'm not sure.

Comment: @msh210 - I don't know much about _esrogim_ or botany, but I'm pretty sure "breed" and "species" refer to genotypic differences while "cultivar" is only phenotypic. . . or something.

Comment: relevant (with pics!): [Which etrog is closest to the gemara's description of "the taste of the tree trunk and its fruit are alike"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95592/11501)

Answer (score 5):

I was raised to use an Esrog from Eretz Yisroel for two reasons. One was to support farmers there, and the other reason was for the love of Eretz Yisroel.

Comment: Nowadays there are many types (species, cultivar, breed, whatever) of Esrogim grown in Eretz Yisroel (for example, there are Genoan Esrogim grown in Kfar Chabad). Unless you mean the type that used to grow wild in Eretz Yisrael years ago?

Answer (score 4):

I know of 4 types or varieties commonly used.

1. The Chazon Ish esrogs (Halpern, Lefkowitz) and similarly the Braverman esrogs (associated with Mahril Diskin) decend from the esrogim that used to grow in Arab villages in the Land of Israel (Balady Citron).
2. The Ordang / Hadara esrogim grown in Israel with certification of Badatz Edah Hachareidis, including "Esrogei Gross" brand. (see [Eretz Yisrael Esrog (Ordang)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117723/eretz-yisrael-esrog-ordang))
3. Esrogim of Calabria, Italy (called in Yiddish "Yannover Esrog") are favored by Chabad and Satmar. In addition to Italy, an orchard of these Esrogs is grown in Israel at Kfar Chabad.
4. Morrocan Esrogs (especially among Morrocan and other Sephardic and Hasidic groups.)
5. Yemenite Esrogs