# Which etrog is closest to the gemara's description of "the taste of the tree trunk and its fruit are alike"?

Tags: sukkot, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, simanim

The gemara in [Sukkah 35a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.35a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) describes one of the characteristics of the *etrog* as

> a tree that the taste of its tree trunk and the taste of its fruit are
>   alike

[dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2013/09/25/the-true-esrog-the-halachic-matter-of-grafted-esrogim/) expands

> The Kapos Temarim (cited by Shut Chasam Sofer, Orach Chaim 207)
>   explains that an esrog is unique in that it has little or no pulp,
>   unlike other edible citrus fruits. The main part of the esrog is
>   therefore its “rind”, which bears a much closer flavor to its bark
>   than does the pulp of any other fruit.

I am aware of at least four common types of *etrogim* grown today: Moroccan, Hazon Ish, Calabrian and Teimani.

Which of these types of *etrogim* corresponds to the gemara and Kapos Temarim description?

Answer (score 13):

I had an opportunity for the first time today to see the inside of four common *etrogim*. I found it fascinating ... and surprising.

Here's a [Moroccan *etrog*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moroccan_citron)

[image: Moroccan etrog outside]
[image: Moroccan etrog inside]

Here's a Hazon Ish *etrog* (for more details, see [here](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-history-and-halacha-of-grafted-esrogim/) under Contemporary Esrogim)

[image: Hazon Ish outside]
[image: Hazon Ish inside]

Here's a [Calabria *etrog*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamante_citron) (some of the pulp on the right side was removed for tasting)

[image]
[image]

Finally, here's a [Teimani *etrog*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_citron)

[image]
[image]

The first three *etrogim* smelled and tasted like ... lemons. The last (Teimani) tasted like ... tree bark. It was clearly the closest to the gemara description.

The Teimani etrog is also closest to the Kapos Temarim description "little or no pulp ... the main part of the esrog is therefore its rind".

PS1: No live etrog was harmed in this experiment - they were all *psulim* for some reason before being cut up

PS2: This answer's only aim is to be educational -- it is not meant to challenge anyone's tradition

PS3: For a long but very interesting history of the different sort of etrogim through the ages, see this [Jerusalem Post article](https://www.jpost.com/Jewish-World/Jewish-Features/The-extraordinary-history-of-the-etrog-2178).

Comment: I think the reverse is true. Citrus trees have that  aroma and taste of citrus. And that is the praise of an esrog, how much the flavor is found in the tree as well. Why would a fruit be praised for tasting like bark?

Comment: @mroll how do you know it's a praise?

Comment: Did you try any of the barks to see if they tasted flavorful in any way? Or were you just comparing to other tree's bark?

Comment: @DoubleAA no I didn't have access to the individual tree barks. But the teimani etrog was the only one not to have "traditional fruit" (i.e., little bags of juice) like the others

Comment: Wait... do you know what tree bark tastes like?  Was that part of this experiment?  If not, why did you taste it?

Comment: @Heshy tree bark tastes like cork

Comment: I'm getting more and more curious.  When did you taste cork?

Comment: @Heshy a few times in my life, do I really have to share here all the stupid things I did out of curiosity? :->

Comment: This is fascinating, even if not particularly scientific :)

Comment: To add to @mroll's point, your answer would be much improved by saying you tried the bark of each of the varieties too.

Comment: @N.T. I hear you but I didn’t and it is hard to go back. They also don’t import bark as they do with etrogim ;->