# Best variety of esrog

Tags: halacha, mesorah-tradition, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

What is the best variety of esrog to use for the Mitzvah? Why, and what is this halachic opinion based on?

I know there is not one consensus answer for this, but there are a variety of halachic sources and opinions that address this based on hard halachic factors, as well as mesorot / minhag.

Comment: highly relevant (with pics!): [Which etrog is closest to the gemara's description of "the taste of the tree trunk and its fruit are alike"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95592/11501)

Answer (score 3):

Yemenites hold that their variety is the only pure etrog and won't use any other. All other kinds, which have edible juice and pulp, have been hybridized with lemons.

Chassidim like a gartel and a Yanever etrog but nobody has such a profound preference as the Yemenites.

Comment: Chabad has a tradition that the first esrogim ever used were from Calabria.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148918/discussion-between-naftali-tzvi-and-).